# SELECT name, max(inhabitants): guaranteed match?

Tags: sqlite

I'm running the following query with SQLITE against a geo database:

```
SELECT name, max(inhabitants) FROM countries GROUP BY continent
```

I'm consistently getting the names and inhabitants of the countries with the largest population, per continent. Is this by chance or some kind of expected (documented?) behavior that I can rely on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this statement:

```
SELECT name, max(inhabitants) FROM countries GROUP BY continent
```

the column `name` although it is in the `SELECT` list, it does not appear appear in the `GROUP BY` clause neither it is aggregated.

For SQLite this is a *"bare"* column and since it is used side by side with `MAX()` aggregate function, the value returned in the results for `name` is the value from the row that contains the max value for `inhabitants` for each `continent`.

And yes, this behavior is documented here: [Simple Select Processing](https://sqlite.org/lang_select.html#simple_select_processing) (at the end of the section).